# How can I use javascript to index input from a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where you must enter a username, but the username cannot start or end with a period (.). This is what I have so far, I feel like I'm close. I think I am making an error in the .value[0] parts.

```
    //Checking Username
    if (document.getElementById("uName").value[0] == "." || document.getElementById("uName").value[-1]) {
        document.getElementById("notification4").innterHTML ="Cannot have period at start or end.";
        submitForm = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("notification4").innerHTML="";
    }
```

My second question is how would I be able to stop the same character from repeating twice in a row? For example you can't have (--) , (//), (%%), (**) etc. I would prefer a similar method to use like above or with regex.

This is the forms HTML:

```
        <label for="uName"> Username: </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="uName" name="uName"> <br>
        <div class= "error" id="notification4"></div><br>
```

Comment: Regexes are very useful in this situation

Comment: You've got a typo, "innterHTML," in the first part of your if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression and the [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function:

```
const regex = /^[.]|[.]$|[^a-zA-Z0-9]{2}/g;
if(regex.test(str)) {
    //code when it matches
} else {
    //code when it doesn't match
}
```

This checks if the first or last character is a dot (^[.]|[.]$) and if there is any character repeated twice that is not a letter or number ([^a-zA-Z0-9]{2}).